# How to prove the norm equality $\|T\|=$sup$\|P_nTP_n\|$ for Hilbert space operator $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $P_1\leq P_2\leq ...$ be finite-rank projections in $B(H)$ such that $P_n$ has rank $n$ and $||P_n(h)-h||\rightarrow 0$ for all $h\in H$. How to prove $\|T\|=$sup$\|P_nTP_n\|$ for a bounded linear operator $T$ on $H$?

It is easy to see $\|T\|\geq$sup$\|P_nTP_n\|$. But how about the "$\leq$"?

Comment: Note that the reuqirements that $P_1 \leq P_2 \leq...$ be finite-rank projections with $P_n$ having rank $n$ are unecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch:** Assume $\|T\|<\infty$. Observe for each $x \in H$ and every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N=N(\varepsilon, x)$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have that
\begin{align}
\| x-P_n x\|_H <\frac{\varepsilon}{\|T\|},\\
\| \underbrace{T x}_y-\underbrace{P_n Tx}_{P_ny}\|_H<\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Next, observe
\begin{align}
Tx =&\ P_nTx+(I-P_n)Tx\\
=&\ P_n TP_nx+P_nT(x-P_nx)+(I-P_n)Tx
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\|Tx\|_H \le&\ \|P_nTP_n x\|_H+\|P_nT(x-P_nx)\|_H+\varepsilon \\
\le&\ \|P_nTP_n x\|_H+\|T(x-P_nx)\|_H+\varepsilon\\
\le&\ \|P_nTP_n x\|_H+2\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Actually, $T$ can be regarded as the operator matrix $\left(
                                \begin{array}{cc}
                                  P_nTP_n & P_nT(I-P_n) \\
                                   (I-P_n)TP_n &  (I-P_n)T(I-P_n) \\
                                \end{array}
                              \right)$